# Generic helper classes in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, helper

I have a pair of classes, A and B, that must hold references to each other. This means that the interface uses clause of A must mention the unit of B, and the interface uses clause of B must mention the unit of A. This is a circular reference in Delphi and not allowed. I am solving the circularity by using the approach found [here](https://blog.spreendigital.de/2011/06/09/solving-circular-unit-references-with-class-helpers/). Basically, A's reference to B is present as expected, but B's reference to A is demoted to a TObject reference, and B uses a helper class to cast the reference to A to the proper type. Here are code snippets to illustrate:

```
unit A;

interface

uses
    B;

type
    TA = class(TObject)
    public
        Name: string;
        B: TB;
    end;

implementation

end.

unit B;

interface

type
    TB = class(TObject)
    public
        Name: string;
    protected
        fA: TObject;
    end;

implementation

end.

unit BHelper;

interface

uses
    A,
    B;

type
    TBHelper = class helper for TB
    private
        function GetA: TA;
        procedure SetA(Value: TA);
    public
        property A: TA read GetA write SetA;
    end;

implementation

function TBHelper.GetA: TA;
begin
    Result := TA(fA);
end;

procedure TBHelper.SetA(Value: TA);
begin
    fA := a;
end;

end.
```

I actually have several pairs of these classes. That's a lot of helper classes, and they're all doing the same thing. So I tried to write a generic helper class that could be parameterized to help a class like B:

```
unit GenericHelper;

interface

uses
    A,
    B;

type
    TGenericHelper<T1, T2> = class helper for T2  //Error: Type parameters not allowed
    private
        function GetA: T1;
        procedure SetA(Value: T1);
    public
        property A: T1 read GetA write SetA;
    end;

implementation

function TGenericHelper<T1, T2>.GetA: T1;
begin
    Result := T1(fA);  //Error: undeclared parameter fA
end;

procedure TGenericHelper<T1, T2>.SetA(Value: T1);
begin
    fA := a;  //Error: undeclared parameter fA
end;

end.
```

My problem is that I don't know enough about generic classes to know whether this will work. I don't know how to resolve the errors shown in the code.

Is there a way to do this?

Full disclosure: the situation is actually richer than this. The pairs are arranged in hierarchies like A-B-C-D where A holds a reference to B, B holds references to both A and C, C holds references to both B and D, and D holds a reference to C. And these are one-to-many relations where A actually holds a list of B's, each B holds a list of C's, and each C holds a list of D's. An ideal solution would not preclude these relations. I also prefer one class per unit rather than combining related classes into single units.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your declaration for `TFriend`?  Is `fChild` a member of `TFriend`?  `fParent`?  It looks like you've declared a generic using generic type names that clash with (ie: are the same as and are hiding) actual type names.  What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I've rewritten the question hopefully for clarity.

Comment: Why not just put A/B in the same unit and use a forward declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is pretty clear

```
 TGenericHelper<T1, T2> = class helper for T2  //Error: Type parameters not allowed
```

You can't use generics like this.  The reason should be obvious because your implementation is trying to access variables that belong to a specific class before you have instantiated the generic class (making the implementation non-generic).

The easiest thing to do is to put A/B(and C/D, etc) into a single unit and simply use forward declarations for the classes.

```
unit ABCD;

interface

    TB = class;
    TC = class;
    TD = class;

    TA = class(TObject)
      public
        B: TB;
        C: TC;
    end;

    TB = class(TObject)
       public
         A: TA;
    end;

    TC = class(TObject)
      public
        B : TB;
        D : TD;
    end;

    TD = class(TObject)
      public
        A: TA;
        C: TC;
    end;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: Thanks. I've done that but it makes files that are unmanageably long or confusing (for me), even when I chop them up with inc files. I should have mentioned that in my disclosure note.

Comment: It depends on whether you want your code to compile or not I guess @David

Comment: @DavidU Well, that seems to be a separate problem with a separate answer.  The answer to your current question ("Can I do this with generics") is simply no.  If the only problem with the above solution is that the source files attain a size which causes you distress then there are other strategies you might use to combat that specific issue.

Comment: Wellll, my approach is clearly wrong. But I didn't take that, or the response, to mean there is no generics solution. Since that seems to be what you're saying, I'll accept the answer.